# Aurelia - How to position navmenu items to the left and right

Tags: aurelia

I have a navmenu that renders routes via a repeat:

```
                <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${ row.isActive ? 'link-active' : '' }">
                    <a href.bind="row.href" if.bind="!row.settings.nav">${ row.title }</a>
```

I have a settings option set as so `pos: "left"`.

I want to use the settings option that is set in each of the routes to split the menu items based on whether they are set left or right.

I wanted to enhance the line:

```
<li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${ row.isActive ? 'link-active' : '' }">
```

sot it also checks the "pos" value in the settings option of the route. I thought I would use "&&" and check for the left or right option however I am unsure how to structure the code to reflect this.

How would I filter out only those "pos" items set to "left"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" 
  if.bind="row.settings.pos == 'left'" 
  class="${ row.isActive ? 'link-active' : '' }">`
```